# Java: how to determine the closer number?

Tags: java

I receive an `ArrayList` with different size (`width` and `height`). According my `ImageView` size, I would like to get the closer width in this `ArrayList`.

What is the best algorithm to get the closer number?

Example: The width is 1024. In this `ArrayList` there are these possibilities:

- width: 58
- width: 256
- width: 512
- width: 1048
- width: 2090

Comment: what about simply subtracting both values from each other?

Comment: The only algorithm to find the closer number I can think of is subtraction.

Comment: Just subtraction would yield negative numbers, make sure to stay positive with `Math.abs()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the array. Compute the distance to the "target" width value for each width in the array (take the absolute value of the difference). Keep track of the item with minimum distance.

Pseudo-code, assumes array has at least one element:

```
int minDiff = Math.abs(targetWidth - width_of_item_0);
int minDiff_index = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < itemCount; i++)
{
    int diff = Math.abs(targetWidth - width_of_item_i)
    if (diff < minDiff)
    {
       minDiff = diff
       minDiff_index = i
    }
}

// minDiff_index now points at the closest item to targetWidth
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the array (assuming the array is sorted in an ascending order), subtracting each value from the width value, when the subtracted value is not lesser than one, calculate the absolute difference between your width value and the value below and lower that value, i.e, the value in the array that was last subtracted and the value that was going to be subtracted next. Of those two value the one which gave the lowest difference should be the closest.

The simple version of what is explained in code:

```
int width;
int result;
int[] widthArray;// the array is sorted in the ascending 

....

int tempDiff=width-widthArray[0];
int i=1;
while(tempDiff<0 && i < widthArray.length){
    tempDiff=width-widthArray[i];
    i++
}
if(i==widthArray.length)
    result=widthArray[i];
else
    result=((width-widthArray[i-1])>(widthArray[i]-width))?
           widthArray[i]:
           widthArray[i-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

In java 1.8 I would use a reduction operation :

```
int closest = options.stream()
                     .reduce(Integer.MAX_VALUE, (best, current) ->
                              Math.abs(current - target) < Math.abs(best - target) ? current : best);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the choices are sorted and have no duplicates, like in your example, you can use binary search. This will return an index, if there’s an exact match (then you can just return the search value), or a negative number, which you can convert to an *insertion point*, using `-returnvalue-1`.

The insertion point is the index of the first number that is bigger than the search value (or the array length if there isn’t one). So if we get an index in the middle, we only have to check the number at that index and the previous one, which is smaller than the search value. Since we know then, which value is smaller and which bigger, we don’t need `abs` to calculate the difference:

```
public static int getClosest(int number, int... from) {
    int ix=Arrays.binarySearch(from, number);
    if(ix>=0) { // exact match
        return number;
    }
    ix=-ix-1;
    return from[ix==0 || ix<from.length && number-from[ix-1]>from[ix]-number? ix: ix-1];
}
```

This can be tested with:

```
int width=1024;
int choice=getClosest(width, 58, 256, 512, 1048, 2090);
System.out.println(choice);
```

which will print `1048`. But always take care to provide the available choices in sorted order and without duplicates…